# $U(1)$ gauge symmetry in superfluid

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, gauge-theory, superfluidity, cold-atoms

The conventional superfluid phase in a Bose-Hubbard ground state has $U(1)$ symmetry. In the presence of spin-orbit coupling (SOC), the superfluid ground state has non-uniform phases. Why do people in literature often say SOC breaks the $U(1)$ symmetry of superfluid?

Comment: Which literature?

Comment: @Qmechanic In this review articel about Spint-Orbit coupled quantum gas http://arxiv.org/abs/1110.6798

Comment: Superfluid by definition spontaneously breaks $\mathrm{U}(1)$ of particle-number conservation. That does not change when you add SOC.